# A*-Search evaluation seems to perform worse than Greedy Search

Tags: java, search, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, a-star

The evaluation function of A* Search is, according to AI: A Modern Approach, `f(x) = h(x) + g(x)`, where f(x) is the evaluation function, h(x) the heuristic function (Euclidian straight line in my case), and g(x) the path-cost. f(x) for greedy search is simply `f(x) = h(x)`.

To test these I made a visualization program.

[image: Greedy Search]

[image: A*-Search]

With obstacle:

[image: greed]

[image: A* obstacle]

As you can see, the greedy search was far more effective than A*. This surprised me, so I wonder if this is expected and whether there is something wrong with my A*-code; either the heuristic or the priority queue.

```
int heuristic(Node n) {
    int i=distanceFrom(n.state, grid.goalState) + n.state.pCost;
    return i;
}

PriorityQueue<Node> front = new PriorityQueue<Node>(30, new Comparator<Node>() {
                    // override compare method
                    public int compare(Node i, Node j) {
                        if (heuristic(i) > heuristic(j)) {
                            return 1;
                        }

                        else if (heuristic(i) < heuristic(j)) {
                            return -1;
                        }

                        else {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }

                });
```

If I try making pCost less significant and more similar to Greedy by dividing it by an integer, it will perform better. Is A* supposed to perform like this?

The entire A* execute-function looks like this:

```
public void execute() { 
    
    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
                
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            boolean retGoal = false;
        
            PriorityQueue<Node> front = new PriorityQueue<Node>(30, new Comparator<Node>() {
                // override compare method
                public int compare(Node i, Node j) {
                    if (heuristic(i) > heuristic(j)) {
                        return 1;
                    }

                    else if (heuristic(i) < heuristic(j)) {
                        return -1;
                    }

                    else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }

            });
            
            Hashtable<State,Node> reached = new Hashtable<State,Node>();                
            State s;
            Node goal = null;
            n = new Node(grid.startState, null);
            int pCost = 0;
            n.pathCost = pCost;
            n.state.pCost = pCost;
            front.add(n);
            reached.put(n.state, n);
            n.state.front=true;
            panel.repaint();
            
        
            
            
            
            while(!front.isEmpty()) {
                Thread.sleep(Main.delay);
                n.state.front=false;
                n=front.poll();
                if(grid.isGoal(n.state)) {
                    goal = n;
                    break;
                }
                
                pCost=n.state.pCost+1;
                panel.repaint();
                for (Node child : expand(n, grid)) {
                    s = child.state;
                    if(!reached.containsKey(s) && !s.isObstacle) {
                    s.pCost = pCost; //steps from goal
                    }
                    if((!reached.containsKey(s) || heuristic(child) < heuristic(reached.get(s))) && !s.isObstacle) {
                        s.reached = true;
                        s.front = true;
                        
                        reached.put(s, child);
                        front.add(child);   
                        
                    }   
                    panel.repaint();
                }
            
            }
            
            if(goal != null) {
                Node n = goal.parent;
                while(n.parent != null) {
                    n.state.isPath=true;
                    n = n.parent;
                }   
            }
            panel.repaint();
                
            return null;
        }
        
        
    };
    worker.execute();
}
```

Comment: In your test scenarios the path is basically an unobstructed, straight line. Try making a labyrinth or at least paths that require moving away from the target. In such cases A* should be much more efficient.

Comment: As the question includes code, please add programming-language-tag.

Comment: Done! Scenarios with obstacles and tag added.

Comment: The frontier of the A* search looks more like a BFS than A*. Pleas post [mre]

Comment: Tip include @username (i.e @c0der) in a comment to address it to this user.

Comment: @c0der I have now included additional code!

Comment: Please post mre as required.

Comment: Note that `heuristic(Node n)` does not return the heuristic but the total cost. Side note: whenever the comparator is used you invoke `heuristic(i)` and `heuristic(j)` up to 3 times.

Comment: @c0der, correct - it should more accurately be named evaluation(Node n)